# Managing of users with OpenAM and springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, openam

How could i manage users in spring-boot application throw openAM and how could my login with every of them? I have already bind it with "Oauth2" and with client but i can not get my demo-user in backend app?

Answer (score 1):

Actually OpenAM does not own identity information, but builds identiy subjects (users / groups) on the fly in memory by consuming identity data from configured user data stores. No matter if you use the 'embedded' users data store or not ... that has just been an option for quicker deployment (for development and showcases).
You could wither use SAMLv2 or OIDC to integrate with OpenAM and retrieve the identity information (user attributes) via SAML attributes or via OIDC claims.
If you prefer OpenAM's proprietary way , you could also use JEE Agent for SSO integration in Spring Boot, but this requires some tweaking.

Comment: And to complete the answer to your question: You can manage the identities in that source with Spring Boot of course. If it's a Forgerock DS either use ldap or it's RESTFUL extension. If it's another directory, use ldap or a 3rd-party library. Or even better if it's managed by IDM, use IDM's generic REST-API.